# Does anywhere else add an 'L' to words ending in a vowel sound?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

When I was six I moved from Manchester (northwestern England) to Bath (southwestern England).  I was baffled to hear my school mates describe the 'aerials' they lived in.

Fast forward many years and I live in Bristol (10 miles from Bath). I find now that sometimes *I* add 'L's to words ending in vowel sounds, involuntarily! Because that's how Bristolians (and Bathonians) speak (although they didn't always - the city name, originally was Brycgstow (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Bristol)).

I'm wondering whether anywhere else routinely adds an 'L', or any other letter for that matter, to words ending with a vowel sound.

Comment: I'm vaguely recalling at least one person I once knew here in the US who spoke like that.  I took it to just be another twist on the common rural accent, but it may well have been "imported" from Bath 100 years ago.  As Ricky says, "r" is more common, but is readily identifiable as a New England accent.

Comment: Yes, it's the L thing that's unusual, I think.  It's very widespread, contagious and often ridiculous - Tinal Turnal, for example.

Comment: @HotLicks  In New England they do the opposite, they omit the "r' after a vowel.  I often heard "I'm buying a new ca.(car)"  "Look at these cads (cards)", etc. when I lived there.

Comment: *Pahk yuh cahr in Haahvahd Yahd.*

Comment: @Centaurus - Really *listen* to someone with a New England accent some time.  The "r" sound isn't dropped, it's just transplanted.

Comment: @HotLicks - You mean, like, to the end of the word?

Comment: @Ricky - Different words.

Comment: (@Centaurus - Find an episode of New Yankee Workshop online.  Listen to how Norm pronounces "drawings".)

Comment: @HotLicks ... Drawrings :) Is there any other way to pronounce it?

Comment: If you think the way Bristolians say "area" is weird, ask them to say "cold".

Comment: A relevant blog post: [bananals in Bristol](http://languagehat.com/bananals-in-bristol/)

Comment: @sumelic - that's interesting.  Thanks.  I'd forgotten about the terrible sisters Evil, Idle and Normal!  The second part was interesting too, even though it seems to be about 'losing' the 'l' sound rather than adding it.

Comment: We add 'r's in Boston, too. *"I sawr him pahk his cahr in Hahvahd Yahd."*

Comment: And 'l's @PeterShor?

Comment: My buddy, who hails from the affluent suburbs of Pennsylvania and is of Eastern European Jewish + Northern Italian extraction, saws "sawL" instead of "saw". He does it consistently. He's the only person I've ever met who pronounces it that way. I do know two Northern California (SF) people who say "obzezzed" instead of "obsessed". And I (NYC native) been told I say "hahrrible" and "aahrange" instead of "horrible" and "orange".

Answer (score 1):

I personally have never heard an l added to the end of most vowel sounds -I live in the United States-, but I have a friend who, when a syllable ends with a "w", will then add an L. This often makes the W have an "ah" sound and I suppose it could then phonetically be considered a vowel. For example, when he says draw or drawing, he pronounces it as "drawl" or "drawling". I assume that it may be because of an accent although I'm not really sure because I have noticed some of his other family members do the same thing.

Comment: Funny, I just wrote [this comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283829/does-anywhere-else-add-an-l-to-words-ending-in-a-vowel-sound#comment686718_283829) under the question: *My buddy, who hails from the affluent suburbs of Pennsylvania and is of Eastern European Jewish + Northern Italian extraction, saws "sawL" instead of "saw". He does it consistently. He's the only person I've ever met who pronounces it that way*. Where is your friend from?

Comment: @DanBron He lives on the west coast, but his family is from the northeast United States. I guess it's a regional thing.

Comment: Does this happen ONLY for '-aw' words?  The Bristol 'l' is indiscriminately added to *any* word with a final vowel sound...

Comment: @Dan In my experience, Yes, but as whether other people add the "l" to the end of any vowel sound- I don't know.